# How to place close icon inside the image: bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap modal to create a thumbnail gallery that displays an attempt of full-size images when its thumbnail is clicked.

I managed to make everything work fine and changed the css a bit but I don't find the way to make the closing "x" button be displayed **inside** the image, preferably in the top right side of it.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="galeria" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="modal-body"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The script that makes the whole thing work:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.thumbnail').click(function(){
    $('.modal-body').empty();
    $("<button type='button' class='close' style='font-size:30px' data-dismiss='modal'>×</button>").appendTo('.modal-body');
    $($(this).parents('div').html()).appendTo('.modal-body');
    $('#galeria').modal({show:true});
  });
});
</script>
```

What should I do to achieve my goal? I am using Bootstrap 3.

Comment: What CSS have you tried? Provide a JSFiddle if possible

Comment: Bootstrap modal css, I didnt' change it. Well, I did, but it doesn't interfere with with what I am asking.

Comment: you may want to try using negative margins in your CSS file. Either that or do not specify the close as 'x' but instead use a div or span with associate background image. You will then have much more control over size, position and display.

Answer (score 2):

**Hello, dabadaba!**

**WORKING FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/Ed2Q7/2/

You'll want to make sure the modal has `position:relative;` and that your image and button have `position:absolute;`.

*So here's an example:*

```
.modal {
    position: relative;
}
.modal img { /* select the image tag inside the modal. */
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:50; /* for good measure */
}
.modal .close { /* select the close button */
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:51; /* place it over the img */
}
```

**Foot note:** If your image is just a background image inside a div, just set the div to `position: relative;` and place the close button inside with the same `position: absolute; top:0; right:0;` style.

Comment: That didn't work. The image is now display pretty close to the bottom in a really tiny section where scrolling is needed. Also there are some weird orange borders that make it wrose. But yeah, the close button is on the image, I will give you that :P How can I position it correctly?